# How do you open additional shared calendars for a user in Outlook 2011

Tags: mac, calendar, exchange-2010, microsoft-outlook-2011

I have 2 users that need to share a calendar, one on Outlook 2010 and the other on Outlook 2011. The Windows user is trying to share an additional calendar and not their primary (personal) calendar with the Mac user, and that's where I think the trouble lies.

If we try to open a shared calendar on the Mac, all we are prompted for is the name of the person. That would be fine if we were sharing the primary calendar, but like I said we want one of the additional calendars and can't see an option to pick a specific calendar.

The Windows user has sent a calendar sharing invitation to the Mac user, but unlike Outlook on a PC and OWA, Outlook 2011 does not allow you to click a button and add the shared calendar to your view.

The calendar structure is below - the *News Articles* calendar is the one we're trying to share, and this opens up fine in OWA on the Mac, so I know it isn't a permissions issue on the calendar.

```
Joe Bloggs - Calendar
Joe Bloggs - News Articles
Joe Bloggs - Some other calendar
```

Is it even possible to do what I want in Outlook 2011, or do I have to find some clunky workaround? If a workaround is necessary, please suggest away because unfortunately I'm totally lost when it comes to Macs.